# Filter data with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
username   score
1          0.0008
1          0.1
1          0.000009
2          0.2
2          0.0098
2          0.7
3          0.99
3          0.019
3          0.0001
```

I need to filter using that condition

```
d = {1: 0.05, 2: 0.01, 3: 0.02}
```

So I need to extract all that less than value in dict for every client.

Desire output:

```
username   score
1          0.0008
1          0.000009
2          0.0098
3          0.019
3          0.0001
```

How can I filter it fast? I know it's possible to do it using loops, but I have a huge dataset includes more than 100 usernames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `map` the `username` with your dictionary `d` and then with boolean indexing, only select those that have `score` `l`ess `t`han the mapping result:

```
df[df.score.lt(df.username.map(d))]
```

to get

```
   username     score
0         1  0.000800
2         1  0.000009
4         2  0.009800
7         3  0.019000
8         3  0.000100
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with a list

```py
sample =  [(1, 0.0008), (1, 0.1), (1, 0.000009), (2, 0.2)]
d = {1: 0.05, 2: 0.01, 3: 0.02}


def check(el):
    return True if el[1] < d.get(el[0]) else False


result = filter(check, sample)
```